# Windows 10 different project mode per desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

When setting up multiple desktops in Windows 10. I would like to have a different project mode for each. This would be helpful when presenting:

- Desktop 1 - project mode extend - showing slides & presenter notes on different monitors
- Desktop 2 - project mode duplicate - showing code on both monitors.

Is it possible to have a different project mode per desktop in this way?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't pressing Win+P easy enough?

Comment: The issue with that is that it isn't a smooth transition when presenting. You either end up displaying your speaker notes, or a black desktop while you change your apps around. That's what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If that's your concern you're probably using the wrong tools. For instance you could use an editor that allows parallel windows and put the second window on the second screen. Especially if you want to frequently switch or e.g. a Streaming Tool with a preview Window like OBS. You could also avoid it by using Win+P and multiple desktops (Win+Ctrl+D and Win+Tab). While switching between extending and duplicating you might also have frequent resolution changes which will probably be more of a problem.